# Convergence of a sequence of convolutions

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
>   $$
> a_0>a_1>\cdots>0
> $$
>   and $M:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n<+\infty$. Denote 
>   $$
> g_n=\frac{1}{a_n}\cdot 1_{[0,a_n]}
> $$
>    and define
>   $$
> f_n=g_0*g_1*\cdots*g_n
> $$
>   where $*$ means the convolutions. Show that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise.

---

What I have done so far is that
$$
f_{n+1}(x)=f_n*g_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\int_{[x-a_{n+1},a_{n+1}]}f_n(y)\ dy. 
$$
and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\not\in[0,M]$ and for all $n$. I don't see how to find a pointwise limit in $[0,M]$.

Comment: The answer really depends on the tools you know / are allowed to use. What are these?

Comment: I suppose this is an elementary exercise in real analysis. Tools in the baby Rudin are assumed I think. I know nothing but the definition and very basic properties of convolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way or another show that $f_1$ is continuous. Now the Fundamental Theorem of calculus shows that $f_n$ is continuously differentiable for $n\ge2$, and in fact
$$f_n'(x)=\frac1{a_n}(f_{n-1}(x-a_n)-f_{n-1}(x))\quad(n\ge2).$$Let $$c_n=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}|f_n'(x)|.$$The Mean Value Theorem shows that $c_n\le c_{n-1}$ for $n\ge3$, so we have $$|f_n'(x)|\le c\quad(n\ge 3).$$

I'm going to stop writing $n\ge2$ over and over. Now $$f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)=\frac1{a_n}\int_0^{a_n}(f_{n-1}(x-t)-f_{n-1}(x))\,dt,$$so again MVT shows that $$|f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)|\le\frac1{a_n}\int_0^{a_n}ct\,dt=\frac c2a_n.$$Since $\sum a_n<\infty$ this shows $f_n$ converges uniformly.

---

**BONUS:** In fact the limit is $C^\infty$. First recall a bit of calculus:

**Lemma** If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n'\to h$ uniformly then $f$ is differentiable and $f'=h$.

Now, for $n>2$ or $n>3$ or whatever "differentiation under the integral" (or various other arguments) shows that $$f_{n+1}'=g_{n+1}*f_n'.$$ So the same argument as showed that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent shows that $f_n'$ is also uniformly convergent, and then the lemma shows that $f=\lim f_n$ is differentiable. Similarly for higher derivatives, either by induction or by noting that $f_{n+1}^{(k)}=g_{n+1}*f_n^{(k)}$ for large $n$.

Comment: Do we have that $f_1$ is continuous and thus $f_2$ is also differentiable?

Comment: @Jack Yes. I was off by one, thinking that $f_n=g_1*\dots$. In fact it's $g_0*\dots$, so every $n$ in my post can be decreased by $1$.

Comment: According to the MVT, one has $f_n'(x)=f'_{n-1}(\xi_x)$ for some $\xi\in(x-a_{n},x)$. How do I get $c_{n+1}\leq c_n$?

Comment: @Jack ??? You believe that $f_n'(x)=f_{n-1}'(\xi)$. So $\sup_x|f_n'(x)|\le\sup_\xi|f_{n-1}'(\xi)|$. Which says precisely $c_n\le c_{n-1}$...

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Thanks! By the way, I was wondering one might have that the uniform limit of $f_n$ is $C^\infty$ since $f_n\in C^{n-1}$. I don't have a proof yet though.

Comment: @Jack Yes it is. See edit...

Answer (score 1):

Consider that every $g_n$ is the PDF of a random variable, say $X_n$. Then $f_n$ is the PDF of $X_1+\ldots+X_n$, and since $\text{supp}(f * g)=\text{supp}(f)+\text{supp}(g)$ and $\sum a_n$ is bounded, $\text{supp}(f_n)\subseteq [0,K]$ and $f_n$ is a compact-supported non-negative function with unit integral. Moreover, $f_n$ is the PDF of a unimodal, symmetric distribution and $f_n\in C^{(n-1)}(0,K)$.

However, a simple argument for proving the pointwise convergence without switching to Fourier transforms still eludes me, but I will keep thinking about it.

A simple way may be to provide some $\ell^1$ or $\ell^2$ bound for $\left|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)\right|$ for every $x\in(0,K)$, as David Ullrich did.

Comment: How about this: Prove inductively that $f_n$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded for $n > 1$. Choose a convergent subsequence with the Arzela Ascoli theorem. Since the partial sums converge a.s. there is only one possible weak limit for the convergent subsequence [note that Scheffe's lemma shows that convergence of the densities implies weak convergence]. This implies that the sequence of convolutions even converges uniformly.

Comment: @Dominik: that works for sure, but do we really need such artillery for dealing with gaussian-like functions?

Comment: $$ f_{n+1}(x)=(f_n*g_{n+1})(x) = \frac 1 {a_{n+1}}\int_{[x-a_{n+1},a_{n+1}]}f_n(y)\ dy = \frac 1 {a_{n+1}} \int_0^{a_{n+1}} f_n(x-u)\,du$$ I wonder if one can use this to get a bound on $|f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|$ and then show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| < \infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : What form of the central limit theorem did you have in mind?  These random variables are independent but frar from identically distributed. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's sort of obvious from the _proof_ of CLT that the limit is gaussian.

Comment: I've just done some simulations. With $a_n = 1/2^n$ I found $X_1+\cdots+X_{12}$ in $200$ instances and got a sample of $200$ that looked as if it's from a normal distribution, and I did this dozens of times with the same result. Then I tried it a few dozen times with $a_n=1/n!$ and maybe the tails were a bit thinner. With $a_n=1/(n!)^4$ the tails were definitely thinner that for the Gaussian, so CLT isn't working there. I did this by using a normal probability plot with $200$ data points each time. Such a plot puts the $200$ observations in increasing order on the vertical axis and${}\,\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$ it puts some numbers that are not _quite_ the expected values of the order statistics from a standard normal distribution. (Just what they are bore some examination, but when the sample size is $200$ there nearly those expectations.) You get a crude approximation to a straight line if the sample is from a normal distribution. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was about to delete my comment.  It's actually not preciselly gaussian. The proof of CLT does show that the sequence converges uniformly; it's clear that $\hat f_n$ converges in $L^1$.

Comment: "These random variables are independent but frar from identically distributed." Even more importantly, the normalization necessary to the CLT is not there.

Comment: @Did Not that it matters, but what normalization do you mean? Of course $\sigma^2(X_1+\dots+X_n)$ is not constant, but it does converge to something finite. Seems to me the reason there's no CLT here is just that $\sigma^2(X_1)$ does not tend to zero.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The problem is that already the sum of the $X_i$ converges to some nontrivial distribution. So if you apply any kind of linear transformation on the sum, it can only converge if the transformation itself converges. But this means the limit of the transformed variable is a linear transformation of the original limit. Since this limit is bounded, no linear transformation can be a nontrivial Gaussian. The problem is that you can't standardize the sequence in a way that creates a nontrivial limit *and* makes any single random variable "insignificant".

Comment: At the risk of repeating differently the crux of @Dominik's argument: in the CLT the increments are divided by $\sqrt{n}$ hence each "shrinks to zero" in the limit. Not here.

Comment: @Did Fine. That's actually more or less what I said - I said the problem was that $\sigma^2(X_1)$ does not tend to $0$. I don't think of "shirinks to zero" as a "normalization", hence the confusion. Not that it matters, there's a simple solution to the problem with just calculus, as nobody seems to have noticed...

Comment: @Did Or to be hugely explicit: Say we have rvs $X_{n,j}$, they all have mean zero, and for every $n$ the rvs $X_{n,1},X_{n,2},\dots$ are independent. Say $S_n=\sum_j X_{n,j}$. If (i) $\sigma^2(S_n)=1$ and (ii) $\lim_n\sum_j\Bbb E|X_{n,j}|^3=0$ then $S_n\to N(0,1)$. Now (i) actually _is_ a normalization, which is why I assumed you were referring to (i). My point was that (i) is not essential, $\sigma^2(S_n)\to1$ would be enough. No, that's not what you meant - the three of us have all been saying that the failure of (ii) (or something similar) is the problem, you just threw me off with the word

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Just a friendly advice: *slow down*.

Comment: @Did ??? Thanks, I guess...

Comment: Do we actually have $f_n\in C^{n-1}([0,K])$?

Comment: @Jack: yes, you are right. Fixed.